# How to allow the folder to be modified by the app only?

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api, cloud

I've a strange requirement regarding for my app which using the `Google Drive SDK`. I'm creating a **folder and a file(Single File)** through app on the `Google Drive`. Now I want that folder to be modified by the app only. Is this feasible?

**Why I need this?**

- I'm writing/syncing my app data to the user's drive. I'm creating a Folder and a file on the Drive.
- Now the file can be modified by the user if he visit the Drive on browser or by some other medium.
- So, If the file is modified, user will not be able to access his synced data on other devices.
- I do not have my own server where I can store the data.

So, I want that file should be modified by the app only. How can I do this? Is this feasible with the current SDKs available? What else are the alternatives for me to get the project done?

**Please Note** : I do not have my own server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is feasible for the reason that I haven't read anything about it in the docs nor have I seen a working implementation of it.

The closest thing I can relate to this is [Permissions for Shared Files's](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing). But the restricting of file/folder happens to both browser and native app. They're always synced.

You can set the restricted folder to Reader role. Users will only be allowed to:

-Read the metadata (e.g. name, description) of the file or folder
-Read the content of the file
-Read the list of items in the folder

Check this [iOS code](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) on how to set the permissions.